# Bootstrap cuts off YouTube Subscribe Button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The Bootstrap css seems to cut off the bottom half of the YouTube subscribe button on my website http://www.isaacadni.com

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In you youmax_clean.css you have to remove your overflow:hidden property
overflow hidden will hide you overlap part.

```
.youmax-subscribe {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

remove this :: overflow: hidden; ::: in your youmax_clean.css